# csv header parsing in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read csv file as dataframe from Azure databricks.
The header columns (when I open in excel) are as follows.
All the header names are in the following format in the CSV file.

e.g.

```
"City_Name"ZYD_CABC2_EN:0TXTMD
```

Basically I want to include only strings within quotes as my header (City_Name) and ignore the second part of the string (ZYD_CABC2_EN:0TXTMD)

```
sales_df = spark.read.format("csv").load(input_path + '/sales_2020.csv', inferSchema = True, header=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the column names after reading in the csv file, using regular expressions to extract the words between the quotes, and then using `toDF` to reassign all column names at once:

```
import re

# sales_df = spark.read.format("csv")...

sales_df = sales_df.toDF(*[re.search('"(.*)"', c).group(1) for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the actual names using `"` to get the desired column names:

```
sales_df = sales_df.toDF(*[c.split('"')[1] for c in df.columns])
```